# While loop ends prematurely

Tags: c++

I am trying out "while" loop while reading C++ tutorial. Surprisingly the below loop always exits on 2nd iteration despite I gave negative integers.

```
while(int sz = get_size() && sz <= 0) ;
```

Below is the get_size() used.

```
int get_size() {
  int a = 0;
  cin >> a;
  return a;
}
```

Comment: Is that semi-colon after the `while` condition a typo when pasting the code or is it really there?

Comment: @JosephMansfield, it is intentionally there to complete a while statment.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your problem is that the statement is equivalent to

```
while(int sz = (get_size() && sz <= 0)) ;
```

Which would be undefined behavior for the first iteration because `sz` is uninitalized.
A solution for this would be moving the declaration outside of the loop.

```
int sz;
while((sz = get_size()) && sz <= 0) ;
```

Comment: It would be nice to state about the priority of the operators. :)

Comment: And to the contrary with `for` loops, in while it isn't custom to declare variables inside the condition. (rarely in specific tasks)

Comment: @Dani, I doubt the interpretation is valid, because: sz needs to be DECLARED first before being compared to 0. Considering that sz is destroyed at the end of each iteration, how can we eval sz <=0 before declaration of (int sz = ...)?

Comment: @user3701346 The interpretation **is valid**.  Why it's valid is a different question, not appropriate for this comments section.

Comment: @GSamaras it's not exactly a precedence issue; the grammar spec for a `while` loop with declarator is basically `while` ( *declarator* = *expression-without-comma* ). So everything to the right of the `=` is part of the initializer for the variable, regardless of precedence.  (As it happens there is no distinction because all operators have higher precedence than `=` (except for comma which is explicitly excluded by the grammar).

Comment: @MattMcNabb, The "=" is not an assignment operator here so precedence rule does not apply. My humble opinion.